Align element in Tikzpicture and PGFPlot
How can I center-align elements within TikZ nodes, particularly when aligning mathematical expressions with equal signs under each other?
Background
I would like to align the equal signs in the following way, similar to how formulas are aligned using the alignat environment in LaTeX. Specifically, in the example below, I want the = sign to be centered at specific x-coordinates.
In the example:
For C_1=5000, the = sign should be centered at x=1.
For C_2=5000 and FV=100000, the = sign should be centered at x=2.
Currently, the text within the nodes is centered, but the = sign is not aligned properly.
The = signs should be aligned with each other, similar to how they would be in an alignat environment in LaTeX.
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

% Mathematics and numbers
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{siunitx} % Für die Formatierung von Zahlen (z.B. \num{})


\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-0.000001, % Set the minimum x value to a small negative value. Otherwise, point t=0 would not show if there is not y-axis (see hdye y axis)
      xmax=2.3, % Set maximum x-value
      ymin=-4, % set minimum y-value
      ymax=0.01, % set maximum y-value
      axis lines=middle, % Draw the x and y axis in the middle of the plot
      axis y line=left, % Draw the y axis on the left side of the plot
      xlabel={$t$ (Bond)}, % Set the x label
      xlabel style=right, % Position the x label on the right
      xtick={0,120/365,1,2},
      xticklabels={$0$,$120$,$365$,$730$},
      font=\footnotesize,
      hide y axis, % Remove the y-axis
      ]
      
      % Vertical grid line at t=120/365
      \draw[dashed,gray!20] (120/365,-1.1) -- (120/365,-2);
      
      % Cash flows at points in time t
      \node at (120/365,-0.4) [below, align=center] {pricing\\day}; % using align=center allows the linebreak in the comment
      \node at (1,-0.4) [below] {$C_1=\num{5000}$};
      \node at (2,-0.4) [below] {$C_2=\num{5000}$};
      \node at (2,-0.7) [below] {$\text{FV}=\num{100000}$};
      
      % Discounting arrows
      \draw[->,dashed,>=stealth]  (1,-1.1) -- (1,-1.5) -- (120/365,-1.5) node[midway, above] {$1-\frac{120}{365} = \frac{245}{365}$};
      \fill (1,-1.1) circle (0.8pt);
      \draw[->,dashed,>=stealth] (2,-1.1) -- (2,-2) -- (120/365,-2) node[midway, above] {$2-\frac{120}{365} = \frac{610}{365}$};
      \fill (2,-1.1) circle (0.8pt);
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}


Here is a way to do it:

assemble your equation from three nodes
where the middle node contains $=$
and is referenced node-wise.

1. Manual trial
At the end of your code I added these lines, which I commented out here for better read-ability:

name the node with the = sign
node names make working with them more easy
use anchors to attach left and right side of the equation

%       Trying node-compund first, then absorbed by \teq{}{}{}{}      
        \node (A) at (2,-2.5) {$=$};
        \node[anchor=east] at (A.west) {$2 - \frac{a}{b}$};
        \node[anchor=west] at (A.east) {$\num{123}$};

2. Absorbing via \newcommand
Once that works, it's time to move this code into a macro and generalize it:

it accepts 4 parameters
1: name, 2: coord, 3: left, 4: right
content from the manual trial is replaced by the variables #1 ... #4

% ~~~ construct the alignment ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\teq[4]{% 1: name, 2: coord, 3: left, 4: right
      \node (#1) at (#2) {$=$};%
      \node[anchor=east] at (#1.west) {#3};%
      \node[anchor=west] at (#1.east) {#4};}

Finally there is some testcode using \teq (tikz-equation):

the first two use absolute coordinates (which are the nodes center with the = sign
the third uses relative coordinates
if \node (B) {}; was placed before that one spells out like \node (C) at ([yshift=-4mm]B) {};

        \teq{A}{1.5,-2.5}{$2 - \frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{123}$}
        \teq{B}{1.5,-3.0}{$\frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{3} \times 3$}
        \teq{C}{[yshift=-4mm]B}{$\frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{3} \times 3$}

4. Final remarks
Adjust spacing around the = sign and/or the left/right part of the equation by the nodes inner margin parameters inside \teq. Or apply some xshift in the left/right nodes, overlapping them.
If you need more parameters, up to 9, e.g. for color options passed, add them the \teq definition.
Please, Do Not ... require loading packages not needed here. It may initiate an update avalanche, which strictly isn't needed just to run your code.


\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

% Mathematics and numbers
%\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{cases}
%
\usepackage{siunitx} % Für die Formatierung von Zahlen (z.B. \num{})
%
%
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%
%\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}


% ~~~ construct the alignment ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\teq[4]{% 1: name, 2: coord, 3: left, 4: right
      \node (#1) at (#2) {$=$};%
      \node[anchor=east] at (#1.west) {#3};%
      \node[anchor=west] at (#1.east) {#4};}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=-0.000001, % Set the minimum x value to a small negative value. Otherwise, point t=0 would not show if there is not y-axis (see hdye y axis)
      xmax=2.3, % Set maximum x-value
      ymin=-4, % set minimum y-value
      ymax=0.01, % set maximum y-value
      axis lines=middle, % Draw the x and y axis in the middle of the plot
      axis y line=left, % Draw the y axis on the left side of the plot
      xlabel={$t$ (Bond)}, % Set the x label
      xlabel style=right, % Position the x label on the right
      xtick={0,120/365,1,2},
      xticklabels={$0$,$120$,$365$,$730$},
      font=\footnotesize,
      hide y axis, % Remove the y-axis
      ]
      
      % Vertical grid line at t=120/365
      \draw[dashed,gray!20] (120/365,-1.1) -- (120/365,-2);
      
%      % Cash flows at points in time t
      \node at (120/365,-0.4) [below, align=center] {pricing\\day}; % using align=center allows the linebreak in the comment
      \node at (1,-0.4) [below] {$C_1=\num{5000}$};
      \node at (2,-0.4) [below] {$C_2=\num{5000}$};
      \node at (2,-0.7) [below] {$\text{FV}=\num{100000}$};
      
      % Discounting arrows
      \draw[->,dashed,>=stealth]  (1,-1.1) -- (1,-1.5) -- (120/365,-1.5) node[midway, above] {$1-\frac{120}{365} = \frac{245}{365}$};
      \fill (1,-1.1) circle (0.8pt);
      \draw[->,dashed,>=stealth] (2,-1.1) -- (2,-2) -- (120/365,-2) node[midway, above] {$2-\frac{120}{365} = \frac{610}{365}$};
      \fill (2,-1.1) circle (0.8pt);
      
%       Trying node-compund first, then absorbed by \teq{}{}{}{}      
%       \node (A) at (2,-2.5) {$=$};
%       \node[anchor=east] at (A.west) {$2 - \frac{a}{b}$};
%       \node[anchor=west] at (A.east) {$\num{123}$};

        \teq{A}{1.5,-2.5}{$2 - \frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{123}$}
        \teq{B}{1.5,-3.0}{$\frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{3} \times 3$}
        \teq{C}{[yshift=-4mm]B}{$\frac{a}{b}$}{$\num{3} \times 3$}
        
      
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}


Great! Works perfectly fine. Thank you!

Thank you :) // One remark: If you only draw one axis using pgfplots, it may be more comfortable to do using plain Tikz. E.g. pgfplots imposes a boundary box, which limits node-text as used now. To "escape", you'd put nodes with larger text between \end{axis} and \end{tikzpicture} ... so you could avoid pgfplots right away ;-)
